# Allocating memory for dynamic array - The block header has been corrupted (FastMM4)

Tags: delphi

I had a topic 1-2 weeks ago about a "The block header has been corrupted" and "Block has been modified after being freed" error.

Somebody gave me a good tip (thanks Alexander) about setting FullDebugModeScanMemoryPoolBeforeEveryOperation to true and finally I have some indications about where is the TRUE location of the error.

The error log points to TScObj object. I have a second object very similar to this one and when I use it the error does not appear. So, this somehow confirms that the error is in this specific object (TScObj).

The log is like this:

```
FastMM has detected an error during a free block scan operation. 
FastMM detected that a block has been modified after being freed. 
Modified byte offsets (and lengths): 15656(1)

The previous block size was: 15672
This block was previously allocated by thread 0xC88, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
402EC9 [System][@ReallocMem]
40666C [System][DynArraySetLength]
40A17D [FastMM4][UpdateHeaderAndFooterCheckSums]
40674E [System][@DynArraySetLength]
4CE329 [ReadSC.pas][ReadSC][TScObj.ReadData][239]
4CDD0C [ReadSC.pas][ReadSC][TScObj.LoadFromFile][168]
4D013E [SmplCubImport.pas][SmplCubImport][TCubImport.ImportSample][164]
40461A [System][@AfterConstruction]
4DC151 [UnitAsmJob.pas][UnitAsmJob][TAsmJob.LoadSample][960]

The allocation number was: 78709
The block was previously freed by thread 0xC88, and the stack trace (return addresses) at the time was:
402E6F [System][@FreeMem]
4068A8 [System][@DynArrayClear]
405DF9 [System][@FinalizeArray]
4CE9F9 [ReadSC.pas][ReadSC][TScObj.ReadData][298]
4CDD0C [ReadSC.pas][ReadSC][TScObj.LoadFromFile][168]
4D013E [SmplCubImport.pas][SmplCubImport][TCubImport.ImportSample][164]
40461A [System][@AfterConstruction]
4DC151 [UnitAsmJob.pas][UnitAsmJob][TAsmJob.LoadSample][960]
```

The thing is that I don't see any place in my code where I could wrongfully allocate memory.

```
type 
 TWordTrace  = array of Word;   
 TDiskTrc  = array of Smallint; 
 var Tracea,Tracec: TWordTrace;

procedure TScObj.ReadData;
Var i: Integer;
    DiskTrc1: TDiskTrc;
    DiskTrc2: TDiskTrc;
    DiskTrc3: TDiskTrc;
    DiskTrc4: TDiskTrc;
begin
 SetLength(DiskTrc1, H.NrOfSamples+1);
 SetLength(DiskTrc2, H.NrOfSamples+1);
 SetLength(DiskTrc3, H.NrOfSamples+1);
 SetLength(DiskTrc4, H.NrOfSamples+1);    <------ log shows error here. <- on DynArraySetLength

 FStream.Seek( H.SOffset, soFromBeginning);

 if H.SampleSize = 1 then
  begin
    for i:= 1 TO H.NrOfSamples DO
     FStream.Read( DiskTrc1[i], 1);
    Unpack(DiskTrc1);

    for i:= 1 TO H.NrOfSamples DO
     FStream.Read( DiskTrc2[i], 1);
    Unpack(DiskTrc2);

    etc...
  end

 else
  begin
   for i:= 1 TO H.NrOfSamples DO
    begin
     FStream.Read( DiskTrc1[i], 2);
     DiskTrc1[i]:= Swap(DiskTrc1[i]);
    end;
   Unpack(DiskTrc1);

   for i:= 1 TO H.NrOfSamples DO
    begin
     FStream.Read( DiskTrc2[i], 2);
     DiskTrc2[i]:= Swap(DiskTrc2[i]);
    end;
   Unpack(DiskTrc2);

   etc...
  end;

 SetLength(Tracea, H.NrOfSamples+1);   
 SetLength(Tracec, H.NrOfSamples+1);
 SetLength(Traceg, H.NrOfSamples+1);
 SetLength(Tracet, H.NrOfSamples+1);   <------ log shows error here. <- on FinalizeArray

 for i:=1 to H.NrOfSamples DO
   begin
     if DiskTrc1[i]< 0
     then Tracea[i]:= 0
     else Tracea[i]:= DiskTrc1[i];

     if DiskTrc2[i]< 0
     then Tracec[i]:= 0
     else Tracec[i]:= DiskTrc2[i];

     etc...
   end;
end;


procedure TScObj.Unpack(VAR DiskTrc: TDiskTrc);
var i: integer;
    Prev: Integer;
    Recover: Integer;
begin
 Prev:= 0;
 for i:= 1 to H.NrOfSamples do
   begin
     Recover := DiskTrc[i] + Prev;
     if (Recover>  32767) OR (Recover< -32768)
     then Recover:= 0;
     DiskTrc[i]:= Recover;
     Prev:= DiskTrc[i];
   end;
 Prev:= 0;
 for i:= 1 to H.NrOfSamples do
   begin
     Recover := DiskTrc[i] + Prev;
     if (Recover>  32767) OR (Recover< -32768)
     then Recover:= 0;
     DiskTrc[i]:= Recover;
     Prev:= DiskTrc[i];
   end;
end;
```

Later during the "load from disk" procedure, the information from the temporary loader object (SC) is transfered into a more "definitive" object, like this:

```
 TSam = class
 etc...                                                
 for i:= 1 to NrOfSamples DO
  begin
   CMX[i].Tracea:= SC.Tracea[i];
   CMX[i].Tracec:= SC.Tracec[i];
   etc...
  end;
```

---

Edit 2: 
The bug appears only when I try to open/load a very specific set of (two) files. For all other files the bug doesn't show.

Comment: What's the declaration of TDiskTrc? Is the element size big enough (at least 2) or are you perhaps overwriting memory by trying to read too many (2) bytes into each element? Also, what do Swap and Unpack do?

Comment: Hi TOndrej.     
I have updated my post to show Unpack. The TDiskTrc can hold those two bytes. Swap is defined in Delphi.system.

Comment: BTW, it would be nice to add a link to this question for old one and visa versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. 
Today I spent the day manually inspecting each line of code. I made quite few changes and finally the problem went away. I haven't tried to see which specific line generated the problem.

Thanks a lot to every body for help !!!

Comment: Are you sure, that problem really disappear? May be you just hide it by suble code changes. That happens a lot.

Comment: I will try today to run it with FullDebugModeScanMemoryPoolBeforeEveryOperation. Takes sometginh like 40 minutes. I really hope it is solved now!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to run this code with FullDebugModeScanMemoryPoolBeforeEveryOperation enabled? Did you try to call ScanMemoryPoolForCorruptions at TScObj.ReadData's start?

If that doesn't help - try to step into that problem call (GetMem?) and follow FastMM's code to see the address of that corrupted header. Just write it down on the paper and restart the program. There are very high chances that the address of this block will be the same.

Set a breakpoint at safe location - i.e. right before "bad things" happens. Once stopped on it - then set a new breakpoint on memory's location - right at this header, which will become corrupted later (be sure not to set it too early).

Then just run your program - the debugger will stop right at this bad code, which tries to modify header.

Answer (score 1):

**I think you've got corruption happening elsewhere, and what looks like a routine call is just unmasking the problem.**  The locations you're pointing to don't seem likely to currupt memory.  Without looking at the code in detail, isolating procedures and testing them carefully, it's awfully hard to guess where the problem lies.  Do you get any warnings when you compile?

Comment: No warnings. The FastMM was not able to provid some real info until I didn't enabled the FullDebugModeScanMemoryPoolBeforeEveryOperation var. But what it is showing now seems realistic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking the error is not ion the code shown, but there is something you should really check:

```
SetLength(DiskTrc1, H.NrOfSamples+1);

  for i:= 1 TO H.NrOfSamples DO
     FStream.Read( DiskTrc1[i], 1);
```

This works thanks to the +1 in Setlength, but are you aware that you are allocating 1 extra item at DiskTrc1[0] that is never used?

I suspect that you mix this with a Setlength(xx, N) somewhere (how is CMX created/dimensioned?).

Note that the normal pattern is

```
SetLength(DiskTrc1, H.NrOfSamples);

  for i:= 0 TO H.NrOfSamples-1 DO
     FStream.Read( DiskTrc1[i], 1);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am ABSOLUTELY aware of that +1.
CMX is also initialized based on NrOfSamples+1.
For some reasons I have started long time ago with that +1 and now a lot of code is based on it. I have to carefully modify the entire code. Probably I should do it today.

Comment: Typo? Normal pattern is with the index starting at 0, not at 1, and looping until Length - 1.

Comment: mghie: Yeah, typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to show more code (like, how is TDiskTrc defined?)

A few points:

Remember that Dynamic arrays are reference-counted, have you tried running with and without Optimizations?

Before using any of these items you may want to assert:

```
  assert(CMX <> nil);
  assert(Length(CMX) = NrOfSamples+1);
```

Is there any code (Swap, Unpack, ...) that stores a reference to an Array?

Are you re-using thos SC objects? (Hint: don't)

Are you clearing any arrays (like DiskTrc1 := nil or SetLength(DiskTrc1, 0) ?

Comment: 1. I updated my post for Unpack. Swap is defined in Delphi.system.
2. I don't reuse the SC but I have a Clear procedure that I call before reading data from disk so I think the object can be reused.
3. No. I don't manually clean up that array.
------------
procedure TScObj.Clear;
begin
 Windows.FillMemory(@H, SizeOf(H), 0);
 FFileName       := '';
 Ads             := '';
 Comments        := '';
 Warnings        := '';
 PrivateData     := '';
end;

Comment: I trust that H doesn't contain any Dyn Arrays?

Comment: H is a packed record which contains many cardinals and 3 static arrays of char.

Comment: Anyway, I just cut the Clear procedure, and the bug is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone seems to be skipping the important error at the start:

*FastMM has detected an error during a free block scan operation. FastMM detected that a block has been modified after being freed.*

An old pointer is being used somewhere.

Since you have no clue on the pointer error you are looking for I would forget it for now and go look for the other one--they might turn out to be related.

Comment: Hi Loren. I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you add few more details? Do you mean that "the old pointer" is a pointer to the SC object? Or a pointer to the "trace" array?
The SC object has a short life (under 100ms) and I use the object only once to load/decode a file from disk. There are few other objects similar to SC to read similar file formats from disk. Based on user's request the program loads the files from disk in those specialized objects then I transfer the data in a unifying object(s) (TCub) which lives for the whole program's span. 
All the other loader objects work.

Comment: FastMM is complaining that you released a pointer and then modified the memory it was pointing to.  While this is dangerous you usually get away with it so it probably isn't causing a crash.  You need to fix it anyway.

Comment: The log an the piece of code for this error is shown in the original post.

Comment: Yes, the log shows the error.  I'm suggesting looking for the cause of it.

Comment: "An old pointer is being used somewhere" No, it is not nessesary so. I can use a very valid pointer, but just overflow it's memory buffer, so I'll end writing into other locations, namely - into block, which was occupied in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Are your arrays 0-based or 1-based?

Multiple times you run loops like this:

```
if H.SampleSize = 1 then
begin
  for i:= 1 TO H.NrOfSamples DO
    FStream.Read( DiskTrc1[i], 1);
  Unpack(DiskTrc1);
  ...
```

Are you sure this is not reading past the end of DiskTrc1?

Comment: 1-based. Just did a search in that unit for "-1" and the string could not be found. I have already checked that about 1000 times. But you are right. That is legacy code. I will change the code to make it 0-based. :)

Comment: PS: FastMM is set to super aggressive debugging mode. I don't remember exactly how it sounds the error message that it throws when you try to read/write past the border of an array, but is not the "header corrupted" one. Also I have the "Range check" ON